# Grid does not respect leftMargin

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

Qt 5.11. I use `Column` to position my controls. For this column element I set `anchors.leftMargin: 10`. All children items respects this except `Grid`.

Screenshot of what I get:

[image]

QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 10

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("System proxy")
        }

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("No proxy")
        }

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("Configure manually:")
        }

        Grid
        {
            columns: 5
            spacing: 10
            Label {text: " "}
            Label {text: qsTr("Address")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Port")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Login")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Password")}
            Label {text: "HTTP"}
            TextField {width: 100}
            TextField {width: 40}
            TextField {width: 100}
            TextField {width: 100}
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the Grid but `RadioButton`, they have an additional padding:

[image]

A [Control](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html) has the following layout:

[image]

So the solution set the `leftPadding` to 0 of the `RadioButton`s:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 10

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("System proxy")
            leftPadding: 0
        }

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("No proxy")
            leftPadding: 0
        }

        RadioButton
        {
            text: qsTr("Configure manually:")
            leftPadding: 0
        }

        Grid
        {
            columns: 5
            spacing: 10
            Label {text: " "}
            Label {text: qsTr("Address")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Port")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Login")}
            Label {text: qsTr("Password")}
            Label {text: "HTTP"}
            TextField {width: 100}
            TextField {width: 40}
            TextField {width: 100}
            TextField {width: 100}
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this means it's not working for Column then... `leftPadding` should be used instead of `anchors.leftMargin`.